# Error en PHP, CRUD: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\wamp64\www\hola\index.php on line 60

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

Estoy tratando de hacer un *crud*, he intentado varios métodos para recorrer el ciclo *while* pero ninguno funciona, me gustaría saber cuál es el error y cómo podría solucionarlo, he leído la documentación del lenguaje mismo e hice todo tal cual sugería allí, espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en esto.

**Código del index:**

```
        <?php include("header.php") ?>
        
        <div class="container p-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
        
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['mensaje'])) { ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            <?php echo $_SESSION['mensaje'] ?>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                        session_unset();
                    }
                    ?>
        
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <form action="guardar.php" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Nombre Alumno</label>
                                <input type="text" name="alumno" id="">
                                <div class="form-grup">
                                    <label for="">Apellido Alumno</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="">
                                </div>
        
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Edad Alumno</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="edad">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Grado Alumno</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="grado">
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary boton" name="Guardar" value="Enviar">
                            </div>
        
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre Alumno</th>
                                <th>Apellido Alumno</th>
                                <th>Edad</th>
                                <th>Grado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
        
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM estudaintes";
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            {
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['title'] ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                
                
                                    } 
                            }?>
                            
                            
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <?php include("footer.php") ?>
```

Este es el código de la bd he leído en varias publicaciones iguales a esta que el error puede estar en el código de la conexión a la base de datos, lo he revisado varias veces pero no veo nada anormal en este.

**Código de la conexión a la BD**

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "alumnos");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//printf("Conjunto de caracteres inicial: %s\n", $con->character_set_name());

/* cambiar el conjunto de caracteres a utf8 */
if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8: %s\n", $con->error);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La traducción al error es que la función `mysqli_fetch_array()` tiene que recibir de parámetro una variable tipo **mysqli_result**, y esta recibiendo una variable tipo **booleana**, esto significa que la variable devuelta por la función `mysqli_query()` es *booleana*.

Si la función `mysql_query()` regresa una variable booleana, puede suceder por varias causas, por ejemplo error en tu query o error en tu conexión, podrías consultar lo que regresa la función `mysqli_error()` para identificar más precisamente que sucede.

Por lo que leo probablemente la tabla esta mal escrita, ya que el nombre de "**estudaintes**" suena medio raro, no habrás querido escribir ¿**estudiantes**?.